# Circles in ellipses

Tags: circles, conic-sections, plane-geometry

If $P$ is a point of a ellipse, show that the circle with diameter $PF$ ($F$ is one of the foci) is tangent to the circle with diameter $2a$ ( $a$ is the major semi-axis of the ellipse) and center coinciding with the center of the ellipse.

I tried to do it using analytical geometry. I used with out loss of generality a ellipse with semi-axi a parallel to the x-axis and center in origin. Then you have $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$ you can find the focus , and the vertices. With that you can write the equation of the circle with center in the origin and radius a. You then use a generic point with coordinates $xp$ and $yp$ that lies in the ellipse. Finally you find the equation of the circle with diameter $PF$ and then show that the distance from the origin (center of big circle) is equal to the difference of the radius of these two circles. I could do that way, but it's too long. I would like to see if there is a shorter solution

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange. You should add to your question your thoughts about how to solve the problem, what you have tried, where you encountered difficulty, etc. Otherwise, your question could be downvoted or closed. Here is a [guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) to asking a good question.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

(This space intentionally left blank.)